# Hooking into tab completion in C

Tags: c++, c, bash

Is there anyway that I can hook into the tab completion for bash from a C or C++ progra, specifically for arguments.

For example if I wanted to do `./myprogram st`<kbd>TAB</kbd> it would complete to `start`.

I wasn't sure if this was something I can hook into during compile and put in like the metadata or if its a bash call/script that I have to make to register the tab completions with bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed possible to customize completion in bash, although it's not something a program can do for itself. [Here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) is the start of a two-part article that explains what you need to know.

Comment: Will this allow dynamic tab completion like in git push where it depends on what branches there are and what remotes there are, or is this guide just for static tab completion options? Or is it simply a matter of updating the file in the /etc/bash_completion.d as you go along

Comment: You actually get to define `bash` functions that generate the completions, so in theory, the sky's the limit. You could indeed provide, for example, a list of available `git` branches as a completion list.